# How to implement database mirroring using SQL on two geographically separate servers

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I need to implement database mirroring on two geographically separate servers.

I have been tasked with ensuring that there should be a backup of the databases that is not more than 1 day behind the live databases.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCuJs.png) is a link of a sketch of what I currently have installed on the servers and how the servers are connected via a WAN. My question is, given my current configuration.

What do I need in order to make mirroring possible? Essentially, what do I need to purchase or upgrade in order to make mirroring possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For mirroring the requirements are as follows:

1. Install same version of WINDOWS server and SQL SERVER`
2. Set same password with same username on windows as well as sql server`
3. Check the port whether 1433 port is available or not,It is sql server default port.
4. Check whether 5022, 5023 port opened or not(It is sql server mirroring port.)
5. After this you can set up mirroring.

Mirroring can be done on same version and edition of sql server.
In case of enterprise edition you can use full features of database mirroring. We can take snapshot backup of database and verify from secondary end.

And in case of standard edition mirroring can be set up but to verify on secondary side mirroring must be broken.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help on the things I know.